# CorrPlot fails to Generate heatmap in R

Tags: r, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

I want to know how to plot a 1000x1000 correlation plot in R using corrplot library.

**My Try:**

```
a <- replicate(1000, rnorm(1000)) 
library('corrplot')
png("Correlation_plot.png")
corrplot(cor(a))
dev.off()
```

**Try 2:**

```
a <- replicate(1000, rnorm(1000)) 
png("Correlation_plot.png")
heatmap(cor(a))
dev.off()
```

**Try 3:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
co <- cor(a)
mco <- melt(co)
png("Correlation_plot.png")
qplot(x=Var1, y=Var2, data = mco)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                    It is not blank @Devashish Das
```

So the problem is not with `corrplot` but with the number of points you are going to plot. In  your case also the plot was being drawn but was not visible.

Here is your code modified which plots the graph with fair visibility.

```
i = 1000
a <- replicate(i, rnorm(i))
png(paste(i,".png"), width = 3200, height = 3200,units = "px",pointsize = 4)
corrplot(cor(a),method = "color")
dev.off()
```

I tried like this for confirming that the plot is very faintly present

```
i = 100
while(i<1001)
{
    a <- replicate(i, rnorm(i)) 
    png(paste(i,".png"), width = 3200, height = 3200,units = "px",pointsize = 4)
    corrplot(cor(a),method = "color")
    dev.off()
    print(i)
    i=i+100
}
```

Here are some results
100[image: 100]

400[image: 400]

700[image: 700]

1000[image: 1000]

Answer (score 1):

I tried `corrplot`  like this way

```
a <- replicate(100, rnorm(100)) 
library('corrplot')
png("Correlation_plot_modified.png", width = 900, height = 900,units = "px")
corrplot(cor(a),method = "color")
dev.off()
```

and got

[image]

So, I think the issue is with the number of points i mean(1000 vs 100) making this difference.

Comment: Gives Blank on 1000x1000

Comment: Ok. I thought it was blank plot.